# When is the connection closed with SignalR from browser

Tags: javascript, signalr

I'm making a little chat application with SignalR 2.0 (just like everyone).

I have a win8.1 application and when the application is closed, the hub receives the OnDisconnected event and removes the user from the list on the hub.
The hub sends to every client that the user has left the chat, so we can visualize that the user has left.

But when I'm using SignalR and Javascript in a webpage and the page gets closed, the hub doesn't get notified that the tab/browser is closed...

Anyone any idea how the connection can be closed?

What i've coded:

**Startup Hub**

```
[assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(ChatServer.Startup))]

namespace ChatServer
{
public class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        // Map all hubs to "/signalr"
        app.MapSignalR();
    }
}
}
```

**Hub**

```
[HubName("ChatHub")]
public class ChatHub : Hub
{
    private static List<User> Users = new List<User>();
    public void Send(string name, string message)
    {
        // Call the broadcastMessage method to update clients.
        Clients.All.broadcastMessage(name, message, DateTime.Now);
    }

    public void UserConnected(string name)
    {
        Clients.Caller.connected(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Users));
        User user = new User() { Name = name, ConnectionID = Context.ConnectionId };
        Clients.Others.userConnected(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(user));
        Users.Add(user);
    }

    public void UserLeft()
    {
        if(Users.Any(x=>x.ConnectionID == Context.ConnectionId))
        {
            User user = Users.First(x => x.ConnectionID == Context.ConnectionId);
            Users.Remove(user);
            Clients.Others.userLeft(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(user), Context.ConnectionId);
        }
    }

    public override System.Threading.Tasks.Task OnDisconnected()
    {
        // Only called when win8.1 app closes
        // Not called when browsers closes page
        UserLeft();
        return base.OnDisconnected();
    }
}
```

**HTML - Javascript:**

Javascript:

```
chat = new function () {

var ChatHub;
// Connecting to the hub
this.attachEvents = function () {
    if ($.connection != null) {
        ChatHub = $.connection.ChatHub;
       $.connection.hub.start({ transport: 'auto' }, function () {
            // Register client on hub
            ChatHub.server.userConnected("web name");
        });
    }

    this.send = function (name,message) {
        if ($.connection != null) {
                //Send chat message
                ChatHub.server.send(name, message).fail(function (e) {
                    alert(e);
                });
        }
    }
  }
};

 window.onbeforeunload = function (e) {
    //This is called when we close the page
    $.connection.hub.stop();
    return "You killed me! :'(";
};
```

**Win8.1 client**

```
    internal async void ConnectToHub(string userName)
    {
        try
        {
            HubConnection hubConnection = new HubConnection(SERVER_PROXY);
            chat = hubConnection.CreateHubProxy("ChatHub");
            Context = SynchronizationContext.Current;

            MakeHubFunctionsAvailableOnClient();

            await hubConnection.Start();
            // Register client on hub
            await chat.Invoke("UserConnected", userName);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw;
        }
    }

    private void MakeHubFunctionsAvailableOnClient()
    {
        //Receive chat messages
        chat.On<string, string, DateTime>("broadcastMessage",
                (name, message, date) => Context.Post(
                    delegate {
                        Messages.Add(new UserMessage() { Message = message, User = name, Date = date }); 
                    }, null
                )
        );

        //Receive all online users
        chat.On<string>("connected",
                (users) => Context.Post(
                    delegate
                    {
                        List<User> userList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<User>>(users);
                        foreach (User user in userList)
                        {
                            Users.Add(user);
                        }
                        Messages.Add(new UserMessage() { Message = "CONNECTED", User = "System", Date = DateTime.Now }); 
                    }, null
                )
        );

        //New user connected
        chat.On<string>("userConnected",
                (user) => Context.Post(
                    delegate
                    {
                        User newUser = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<User>(user);
                        Users.Add(newUser);
                        Messages.Add(new UserMessage() { Message = newUser.Name + " CONNECTED", User = "System", Date = DateTime.Now }); 
                    }, null
                )
        );

        //User left, remove user from list on client
        chat.On<string>("userLeft",
                (user) => Context.Post(
                    delegate
                    {
                        User newUser = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<User>(user);
                        User y = Users.First(x=>x.ConnectionID == newUser.ConnectionID);
                        bool ux  = Users.Remove(y);
                        Messages.Add(new UserMessage() { Message = newUser.Name + " left the conversation", User = "System", Date = DateTime.Now });
                    }, null
                )
        );
    }
```

My hub doesn't trigger OnDisconnected, when i close tab / browser / navigating to other site
The site is a singe page website (for the moment)

What browser am i using? 
Chrome: Version 32.0.1700.68 beta-m

Internet Explorer 11

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I guess your question is how to detect whether a specific user left or closed the browser. When a user comes in or leaves, send a notification to other users.

I think the problem is you didn't handle `OnConnected` and `OnDisconnected` properly.
To make it work, first you need to know each client connecting to a hub passes a unique connection id. You can retrieve this value in the Context.ConnectionId property of the hub context. When each client comes in, they go through `OnConnected`, when they leave, they go through `OnDisconnected`. Below is a working example:

**Hub Class**

```
[HubName("ChatHub")]
    public class ChatHub : Hub
    {
        private static List<User> Users = new List<User>();
        public void Send(string message)
        {
            var name = Context.User.Identity.Name;
            Clients.All.broadcastMessage(name, message, DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString());
        }
        public override Task OnConnected()
        {
            User user = new User() { Name = Context.User.Identity.Name, ConnectionID = Context.ConnectionId };
            Users.Add(user);
            Clients.Others.userConnected(user.Name);
            return base.OnConnected();
        }
        public override Task OnDisconnected()
        {
            if (Users.Any(x => x.ConnectionID == Context.ConnectionId))
            {
                User user = Users.First(x => x.ConnectionID == Context.ConnectionId);
                Clients.Others.userLeft(user.Name);   
                Users.Remove(user);
            }
            return base.OnDisconnected();
        }
    }
```

**View**

```
<input type="text" id="message" />
<button class="btn">Send</button>
<ul id="contents"></ul>

@section scripts
{
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.signalR-2.0.1.js"></script>
    <script src="/signalr/hubs"></script>

    <script>

        var chatHub = $.connection.ChatHub;
        chatHub.client.broadcastMessage = function (name, message, time) {
            var encodedName = $('<div />').text(name).html();
            var encodedMsg = $('<div />').text(message).html();
            var encodedTime = $('<div />').text(time).html();
            $('#contents').append('<li><strong>' + encodedName + '</strong>:&nbsp;&nbsp;' + encodedMsg + '</strong>:&nbsp;&nbsp;' + encodedTime + '</li>');
        };
        chatHub.client.userConnected = function (data) {          
            $('#contents').append('<li>Wellcome<strong>' + '</strong>:' + data + '</li>');
        };
        chatHub.client.userLeft = function (data) {
            $('#contents').append('<li>Bye<strong>' + '</strong>:' + data + '</li>');
        };
        $(".btn").on("click", function() {
            chatHub.server.send($("#message").val());
        });
        $.connection.hub.start().done(function() {
            console.log("connected...");
        });
    </script>
}
```

Comment: The problem is that the hub doesn't trigger OnDisconnected when the browser gets closed / the user navigates to another page or the user closes the tab. Even when i call $.connection.hub.stop();
Ps: I updated my question with some code.

Comment: Hi @Lin, if i execute your code, i get these error: "Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'connected'". When i log the client object -> console.log($.connection.ChatHub.client); results in: Object {}. If i use ChatHub with a lowercase c, chathub is undefined

Comment: hi @brouckaertd, I guess the problem is you don't have the OnConnected function in your hub class. I created a similar chat function for you, take a look.

Comment: A little late answer, but the onConnected event is overridable. So from what I know, it means it's always called. If I implement the onConnected event with custom code. I think that won't  solve my problem.
But i will try your code, and hopes it works.

Comment: I used my hub with your client. And it works! Thank you! Now only determine what's the difference between our code

Answer (score 8):

You might be running into the issue described here: https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/issues/2719

tl;dr: There is a bug introduced in Chrome 31 that is already fixed in Chrome Canary, that prevents SignalR from immediately trigger OnDisconnected.

If you are, you can use the workaround I suggested in the issue which is to add the following to your JS code.

```
window.onbeforeunload = function (e) {
    $.connection.hub.stop();
};
```

Even with this bug and without the workaround I would expect SignalR to raise OnDisconnected approximately 35s after the browser exits the page hosting SignalR.

Can you provide more details about which browsers you are experiencing this issue with and in what situations? (e.g. closing the tab, closing the window, refreshing, navigating to another page on the same site, navigating to a different site, etc.)

Comment: I've added some code and information to my question.
When i use $.connection.hub.stop(); the hub doesn't trigger OnDisconnected. Even when i wait 35s or more.